# BPMN: How to model one task that can be done by two different roles? (FE: Customer is either added by 'sales' or 'administrative staff')

Tags: modeling, bpmn

I am trying to model a situation in which a customer is added by either sales or an administrative assistent. They both have their own lane. I think using an OR or a 'AND' (paralel) gate would not really accurately reflect the situation.

How would you model this?

It would be great if there was an optional (either or) parallel gate but I don;t know if that exists.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean, whoever comes first will work on this activity. Therefore, a gateway cannot be the solution. It would need to have a condition, that is evaluated *before* one of the two activities get enabled.

This is what I would do: Create a new lane "customer admin" and specify somewhere else, that sales and adminstrative assistants are "customer admins".

If you duplicate "add customer" to show it in both lanes, you also have to model how one activity gets revoked, as soon as the other role starts working on it. If you want to model this, it gets really complicated. Of course, maybe a simple note could be sufficient, but I guess you are looking for a solution in BPMN.

If this activity would be the first in a process with empty start event, there is a simpler solution: Just use two empty start events and let the starter of the process decide, which one is to be used.